# Why the sent message in chat app is repeated the first time a message is sent?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an android chat application using firebase database and I don't know what is going wrong with the code, as the first time a message is sent by user1, it gets repeated, as it is, for user1 and the same happens when the user2 sends a message the first time.
What I am referring, looks like this:

[image: image1]

and

[image: image2].

Here's the code for getting the message from firebase database.

```java
usersRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                ms = dataSnapshot.child("rec_msg").getValue(String.class);
                fUid = dataSnapshot.child("fromUID").getValue(String.class);

                if(ms!=null && !ms.equals(""))
                    addMessageBox(ms);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                ms = dataSnapshot.child("rec_msg").getValue(String.class);
                fUid = dataSnapshot.child("fromUID").getValue(String.class);

                if(ms!=null && !ms.equals(""))
                    addMessageBox(ms);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

And the code for 'addMessageBox(String msg)' is like:

```java
private void addMessageBox(String message){

           TextView tv = new TextView(Main5Activity.this);
           tv.setText(message);
           tv.setPadding(20, 30, 30, 20);
           tv.setTextSize(1, (float) 20.1);

           LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           lp2.weight = 1.0f;



           if (mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(fUid)) {

               lp2.gravity = Gravity.END;
               tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_grey);

           }
           else if(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid().equals(toUid)){

               lp2.gravity = Gravity.START;
               tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_rectangle_violet);

           }

           tv.setLayoutParams(lp2);
           layout.addView(tv);
           scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);


    }
```

```java
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
```

Comment: Can you show what your database looks like?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are adding a message on both OnChildChanged and OnChildAdded. The first time a message is sent, both the methods are invoked, resulting in the same message being added twice. Try keeping your logic only in OnChildAdded method.

```
usersRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            ms = dataSnapshot.child("rec_msg").getValue(String.class);
            fUid = dataSnapshot.child("fromUID").getValue(String.class);

            if(ms!=null && !ms.equals(""))
                addMessageBox(ms);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This will and does result in the new messages not being displayed at all, during the chat. Also if we just keep the data adding code in only 'onChildChanged()' part, even then text gets displayed twice, now just with the padding of the sending user(grey) instead of violet(as in earlier).